# Replacing a specific font in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I'd like to replace a specific font in Google Chrome, Meiryo with Yu Gothic, as I personally find Meiryo very ugly. I first tried using this method [Replace only a specified font in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/528343/replace-only-a-specified-font-in-chrome) and replacing Verdana with Meiryo and Courier New with Yu Gothic, but that didn't work for me.

Does anyone know how to make an extension that replaces Meiryo with Yu Gothic?